# Excute Scoring Tasks in Game in Background objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer, uibackgroundtask

I am creating a game in which the user is rewarded points while the app is in the background or not running. If the application is fully closed out, they should still get points. Currently I am doing this using an NSTimer, however I have read everywhere that timers can not execute in the background. Here is what I have and how should I fix it:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    score = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"score"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:nil];
    timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(score) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}

-(void) score{
    score++;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:score forKey:@"score"];
}
```

Comment: There is specific time allowance for allow background tasks to run when your app is in background. When you pass that time, you can no longer run any tasks. You should look into notifications instead of running tasks on background.

Comment: I will look into that @TejaNandamuri

Answer (score 1):

You can set a "end time" with NSUserDefault in `applicationDidEnterBackground` method.
In `applicationDidBecomeActive` you get the elapsed time since the "end time" and you set your score from this elapsed time.

Comment: Okay, but how would I get the elapsed time from the end time